# Login Email with Google to Specific Domain Name

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am not able to find any documentation on how to restrict the login to my web application  to only accept authentication requests from users with an email on a specific domain name or set of domain names. I would like to block as opposed to blacklist.

Does anyone have any document or template which how to achieve using jsp,angularjs,javascript, documentation on the officially accepted method of doing so, or an easy, secure work around?

For the record, I do not know any info about the user until they attempt to log in through Google's OAuth authentication. All I receive back is the basic user info and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method of string class String. contain("@yourdomain") it will return boolean value true or false
It will go like.. 
    `if(request.getParameter("email").contains("@yourDomainName"))
Do something;`